# Setting textfields value from a csv-like string

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a csv-like string :

```
var ret = "21-01-2015|0|50|31-01-2015|0|0|5000000";
```

The separator is then "|".

There are HTML textfields :

```
<input type="text" name="P_FIN_DECLARATION" id="P_FIN_DECLARATION" class="input-small datepick validate[required]"/>
<input type="text" name="P_TAUX_PENALITE" id="P_TAUX_PENALITE" maxlength="5" class="input-mini validate[required]"/>
<input type="text" name="P_TAUX_MAJORATION" id="P_TAUX_MAJORATION" maxlength="5" class="input-mini validate[required]"/>
<input type="text" name="P_LIMITE_PAIEMENT" id="P_LIMITE_PAIEMENT" class="input-small datepick validate[required]"/>
<input type="text" name="P_TAUX_1" id="P_TAUX_1" maxlength="5" class="input-mini validate[required]"/>
<input type="text" name="P_TAUX_2" id="P_TAUX_2" maxlength="5" class="input-mini validate[required]"/>
<input type="text" name="P_PLAFOND" id="P_PLAFOND" maxlength="50" class="input-small validate[required]"/>
```

Each data from the string are associated exactly matching each textfield's sequence : for example 21-01-2015 is for P_FIN_DECLARATION , and so on.

How to set values of the textfields from the data parts of the string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var ret = "21-01-2015|0|50|31-01-2015|0|0|5000000".split('|');
// split function splits a string into an array

$('input').each(function (index) {
  $(this).val(ret[index]);
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/bureka/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 2):

**P.S. You do not need JQuery to do this simple task!!**

You can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/t33553x2/

```
var ret = "21-01-2015|0|50|31-01-2015|0|0|5000000";
var fieldArr = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

var retArr = ret.split("|");
for(var i=0; i<fieldArr.length; i++) {
    var field = fieldArr[i];
    field.value = retArr[i];
}
```

Comment: Yes ! but we are following new stuff :) and look how elegant is it to do with jQuery in Alexander's response :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.split()` to achieve the same effect as php's explode and use `$.each` to iterate over the array pretty easily,

```
var elems = $('input[type="text"]');

$.each("21-01-2015|0|50|31-01-2015|0|0|5000000".split('|'), function(i,val){
   elems.eq(i).val(val)
});
```

---

Or you can do like,

```
var arr = "21-01-2015|0|50|31-01-2015|0|0|5000000".split('|');

$('input[type="text"]').val(function(i){ 
    return arr[i]; 
});
```